# IAsyncResult returned from Begin method is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I need to return null if i get some error. But this throws,

```
IAsyncResult returned from Begin method is null.
```

Here is my code?

```
        try
        {
            var url = (string)state;
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            return request.BeginGetResponse(cb, request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
        }
        return null;
```

How to return empty IAsyncResult?

Comment: I can't see any way that this code block would throw. You might be breaking on every exception instead of only on unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions, to start with...

Comment: @JonSkeet, This is inside thread pool thread and I am using asp.net, so it might tear down my process.

Comment: @Rotem, might be invalid url or url does not exist

Comment: There's something wrong in the request, and as @JonSkeet said, throw the exception to find out!

Comment: @user960567 Why would that matter, you've wrapped a try over all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement this interface and it will work.

```
public class NullAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
{
public object AsyncState
{
get { return null; }
}

public System.Threading.WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
{
get { return null; }
}

public bool CompletedSynchronously
{
get { return true; }
}

public bool IsCompleted
{
get { return true; }
}
}
```

then in your code :

```
try
{
var url = (string)state;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
return request.BeginGetResponse(cb, request);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
return NullAsyncResult();
```